# Shell script for checking if array is empty and restarting program if so

Tags: arrays, shell, sh

I want to make a shell script that keeps running to check if my two light weight web servers are still running, and restart them if one is not.

I can use the the command `pgrep -f thin` to get an array (?) of pids of my server called `thin`.

When this returned array has a count of zero I want to run a command which starts both servers:

```
cd [path_to_app] && bundle exec thin -C app_config.yml start
```

`pgrep -f thin` returns all the pids of the servers that are running. For example:

> 23542
> 23425

I am new to shell scripting and don't know how to store the results of `pgrep-f thin` in an array. E.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do

    arr=$(pgrep -f thin) # /edited and now THIS WORKS!


    #Then I want to check the length of the array and when it is empty run the above 
    #command, e.g.,

    if [ ${#arr[@]} == 0 ]; then
        cd [path_to_app] && bundle exec thin -C app_config.yml start
    fi

    #wait a bit before checking again
    sleep 30
done
```

The first problem I have is that I cannot store the `pgrep` values in an array, and I am not sure if I can check against zero values. After that I am not sure if there are problems with the other code. I hope someone can help me!

Comment: "just stored string variables" - because you use the syntax for creating an array, and not the syntax for program execution.

Comment: Hi @KarolyHorvath, I have the variables now.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your description... you say you want to start the servers if EITHER is not running, but your code only starts them if BOTH are not running. In theory you should check for an array length of 1 too, and kill the and running server before restarting both...

Comment: I @MarkSetchell, true, I now use `if [ ${#arr[@]} -lt 2 ]; then
(...) restart; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute the command:

```
arr=($(pgrep -f thin))
```

> [...] when it is empty

If you only check for emptyness, you can directly use the exit status of `grep`.

> ```
> -q, --quiet, --silent
>      Quiet;  do  not write anything to standard output.
>      Exit immediately with zero status
>      if any match is  found,  even  if  an  error  was  detected.
> ```